# Mixed distribution of product of Bernoullie and Gaussian r.v

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Confused with the formulation of density function of the following mixed distributed random variable $Z$.

$$Z \equiv X  \cdot Y,$$ where $( \cdot)$ is product operation, and $X$ and $Y$ being independent,

$X$ is [Bernoulli distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)  i-e  $X \sim B(n=1,p)$,

and $Y$ is Gaussian distributed  i-e  $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\sigma).$

**My Thought**
The joint distribution $f(X,Y)=\begin{cases}(1-p)\frac{e^{-y^2/2 \sigma^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} & x=0,y  \\ p\frac{e^{-y^2/2 \sigma^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} & x=1,y \end{cases}$

if this is correct, then final step to take would be to marginalize in one variable above (i-e marginalize either X or Y).

Any clue or idea !

Comment: With probability $1-p$, the value of $Z$ is .....

Comment: you mean this ? $p(Z)= \begin{cases} \mbox{indeterminate} &\mbox{if } z = 0 \\ 
(1-p)\frac{e^{-z^2}/2 \sigma^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma} & \mbox{if } z \neq 0. \end{cases} $